# XML attributes to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, arrays

I need to create a javascript array or object from an XML file that is structured as follows:

```
<ITEMS>
    <TXT id="8" typ="1" pid="7" x="708" y="216" fcol="6777213" txt="sometext" hcmd="0" click="1"/>
    <TXT id="9" typ="1" pid="2" x="708" y="144" fcol="1231341" txt="some other text" hcmd="0" click="0"/>
    <GRAF id="7" typ="0" x="20" y="84" hcmd="0" click="0"/>
    <CAM id="32" typ="0" x="383" y="531" url="some url" hcmd="0" click="0"/>
</ITEMS>
```

As you can see there are a few different element names in  and they do not all have the same attributes.

I need to be able to retrieve the items by ID and preferable be able to retrieve the ID's of all TXT-items, or CAM-items, or y-items etc.

I'm using jQuery to parse the XML: `$(xml).find('ITEMS').children('TXT').each(function() { }` and with code like `$(this).attr("txt");` I'm building up the DOM - item by item - and it starts to get slow. I have a feeling there must be a better way. Store the XML in an array or object, process (sort) it and then build up the DOM at once.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you've already thought about using json?

Comment: Yep. The server is a closed solution, so I'm stuck with the XML.